# Taks List/Workflow - Reflecting changes across lists

Tags: workflow, designer-workflow, task-list, updatelistitems, update

I have created a task list named 'Project Planner' and I have created 4 other identical lists for each business area.

One of the columns in this list is a choice field named 'Business Area' with 4 options (Let's just call them options 1 to 4) that once selected will copy the item into the relevant list for that business area.

So we now have a total of five lists I have created a workflow on the 'Project Planner' list with the logic

If 'Business Area' equals option 1 then copy current item to list 1 (Repeated for each option and list)

So this should give us 'Project Planner' showing all tasks and 4 sub lists showing only tasks that apply to that area.

What I need to do now is create some kind of workflow that will update items if modified. (So if business area is area 1 and the task is modified in the Project Planner the copied item in list 1 will be updated and vice versa).

The reason I have broken the list up rather than creating views is because on the landing page of this site there will be a calendar view with overlays that are color coordinated for each business area and can be viewed by all users.

Any help at all would be appreciated and if there's an alternative way to achieve this please let me know.

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue using a workflow to delete older created versions.

First of all I had to create a column called "ID-Column" on all five lists

**Workflow:**
Update item in **current item** (ID-Column to value current Item:ID)

if **Current Item:ID-Column** equals **List 1:ID-Column**
(Data source: List 1, Field from source: ID-Column, Field: ID-Column, Value: Current Item: ID-Column)

Delete item in **List 1**
(List: List 1, Field: ID-Column, Value: Current Item:ID-Column)

If **Current Item:Business Area** equals **List 1**
Create Item in **List 1** (Output to Variable: create)

Set this to automatically run on creation and modified. This will check the ID against existing records in the sub lists and delete any record with a matching ID then create an updated version in the list. This will prevent you being able to record version history but will keep the lists in sync.

Repeat the workflow for each sub list and again on each sub list to do the same in the parent list.

If anyone is having a similar issue this may save you some time and if you get stuck feel free to contact me for further info.